# iOS 9 iPad air text-shadow rendering artefacts

Tags: css, ipad, mobile-safari

With html as follows:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum Incididunt minim enim pariatur ex in irure Duis deserunt.</h1>
```

And css:

```
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000;
}
```

I am getting some odd shadow artefacts in rendering on iOS 9.3.2 on iPad air (1 and 2). The problem was not reproducible on iPad mini 1 or 2 or on on iOS 10.1.

I experimented with changing the font, line height, alpha transparency in shadow etc... and the culprit seems to be simply using any text-shadow with a raw h1 element (and I assume other elements). The problem seems to be easier to reproduce when font size is larger and text colour is white, but is definitely there with only text shadow property (might have to pinch zoom in and out a bit to re-create it).

The problem as captured in the screenshot provided is quite minor, but with different text/font sizes it is sometimes much worse.

Does anyone have any information about the root cause? Does anyone know exactly what devices/os versions this affects? Does anyone know of any good workaround for the issue?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t7ccn528/

[image: ipad render artifacts]

Comment: work fine on my devices.

Comment: @ZeevKatz what model/ios version did you try it on?

Comment: iPad 2 iOS 9.5.2 and iPhone 5s and 6 with iOS 10.0.2

Comment: @ZeevKatz thanks for the feedback - so far we have only seen problem with iPad Air and iOS9 combo. Good to confirm some more devices.

Comment: maybe this is caused by tabs?

Comment: @DeyaEldeen do you mean tab character..? I don't think have any in the demo fiddle where the issue is 100% reproducible on iPad air with iOS 9. Or am I missing something..?

Comment: there are different types of spaces too, maybe you used a different ascii space in the broken areas?

Answer (score 2):

Try making the h1 positioned relative or absolute (whichever works for it's placement in the tree).  Then add a top:0;

Also try:

Mess with the font-smoothing CSS properties on the H1, specifically subpixel-antialiased.  Try those two separately and together.  I can't replicate on my Browserstack VM, otherwise, I'd be able to probably figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately they did not fix the problem. Do you have any other ideas?